# Brain js for sequential times predictions

Tags: node.js, machine-learning

Does anyone tried to implement a sequential times predictions model with brainjs ?
I have dates of an occuring event, and I want to find when will be the next occuring event.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/BrainJS/brain.js#for-training-with-rnntimestep-lstmtimestep-and-grutimestep

```
var net = new brain.recurrent.LSTMTimeStep();

net.train([
  [1, 3],
  [2, 2],
  [3, 1],
]);

var output = net.run([[1, 3], [2, 2]]);  // [3, 1]
```